# Movie ratio in subplot - Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the code below I have four subplots: video, a cropped video and two sine graph plots. The issue I encounter is that the movie playing loses its original ratio. How can set ratio in the subplot to be correct?

Code:

```
clc;     
close all;   
imtool close all;   
clear;  
fontSize = 10;

folder = fullfile(  'D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\images\imdata');
movieFullFileName = fullfile(folder, 'rhinos.avi');
firstFrame = VideoReader(movieFullFileName);
frame = read(firstFrame,1);

videoObject = VideoReader(movieFullFileName)
numberOfFrames = videoObject.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = videoObject.Height;
vidWidth = videoObject.Width;

figure;
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
close(gcf)

for frame = 1 : numberOfFrames
        thisFrame = read(videoObject, frame);
        hImage = subplot(4, 2, 1);
        image(thisFrame);
        caption = sprintf('Frame %4d of %d.', frame, numberOfFrames);
        title(caption, 'FontSize', fontSize);

        hPlot = subplot(4, 2, 2);
        thisFrameCrop = imcrop(thisFrame,[150 40 30 50]);
        imshow(thisFrameCrop);
        caption = sprintf('Region of interest - Frame %4d of %d.', frame, numberOfFrames);
        title(caption, 'FontSize', fontSize);
        drawnow;    

        subplot(4, 2, 3);
        x = linspace(0,10);
        y1 = sin(x);
        plot(x,y1)

        subplot(4, 2, 4); 
        y2 = sin(5*x);
        plot(x,y2)
end
```

Comment: From my understanding, the solution is already in your question, use `imshow` as you did for the cropped subsection. From the documentation "imshow uses the default display range for the image data type and optimizes figure, axes, and image object properties for image display."

Comment: Do you mean correcting the Aspect Ratio?  Daniel gave you the answer: Replace `image(thisFrame);` with `imshow(thisFrame);`